# How to use jQuery .hover() in combination with Overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Well, i am stucked and can't find the answer myself. Hopefully someone can give me a hint.

I try to fullfill the following requirements:

- There should be a Newsblock within a HTML Page with a fixed width and
  height.
- In this Newsblock only the title of the news are visible.
- Those news are "collapsed" by default and should "expand" if the Mouse is over it.
- Due the fact that the 'Newsblock' is limited by its height, there should be a Scrollbar visible. But only if the currently expanded news makes it necessary, so the user can Scroll down.
- Newstitle and Newstext should never leave the Newsblock.

so far so good, i was able to fullfill all those demands except the one with the Scrollbar. If i try to reach the Scrollbar out of the currently expanded news it collapses again and the Scrollbar disappears. I understand that my .hover is configured that it always SlideUp if i leave the newsentry and the Scrollbar isn't a part of the newsentry div. But i have no idea what to change to still have an overall Scrollbar for the Newsblock, but won't disappear if i try to 'reach' it.

P.s.: A Scrollbar only per Newsentry looks weird. Thats why i want 'bind' the scrollbar to the parent container :S

**HTML**

```
    <div id="newsblock">
        <div> // some auto generated div's i have to life with, so the news entries are not 'direct' children of the newsblock.
            <div class="newsentry">
                <div class="newstitle">...</div>
                <div class="newstext">...</div>
            </div>
        ... another 9 'newsentry' divs.
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
    $(".newsentry").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children(".newstext").stop(true,true).slideDown();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children(".newstext").stop(true,true).slideUp();
        }
    );
```

**CSS**

```
    .newsblock {
        height: 200px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

Comment: Can you put the `overflow-y` on the `.newsentry` instead? That would solve your problem. Otherwise it is going to be quite complicated to solve.

Comment: I can, but, as mentioned before, if i to so the scrollbar will be only display within the corresponding news. This also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of closing a `.newsentry` when the cursor goes out of it, a solution can be to close it only when it enters another `.newsentry` or when it leaves `#newsblock`.
The scrollbar being part of `#newsblock`, the entry isn't closed anymore when you go on it.

**EDIT:** Following our discussion about the scroll issue, I added a `step` callback to the closing animation to make sure that the top of the `.newsentry` getting opened remains visible when the other entries are getting closed.

Here is a working example:

```js
var $newsblock = $("#newsblock");

function closeAllNews(slideUpArgs){
    return $(".newstext").stop(true).slideUp(slideUpArgs);
}

function openNews(news, slideDownArgs){
    $(news).find(".newstext").stop(true).slideDown(slideDownArgs);
}

function ensureNewsTopVisible(news){
  // Check if the top of the newsentry is visible...
  var top = $(news).position().top;
  if(top < 0){
    // ...and if not, scroll newsblock accordingly.
    $newsblock.scrollTop($newsblock.scrollTop() + top);
  }
}

$(".newsentry").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // When the mouse enter a news entry...
    $this.on("mouseenter", function(){
        // ...close all opened entries (normally there is at most one)...
        closeAllNews({
          // (while making sure that the top of this entry remains visible
          // at each step)
          step: ensureNewsTopVisible.bind(null, $this)
        });
        // ...open this newsentry.
        openNews($this);
    });
});

// When the mouse get out of the newsblock, close all news.
$newsblock.on("mouseleave", closeAllNews);
```

```css
.newstitle {
    font-size: 2em;
}
.newstext {
    display: none;
}
#newsblock {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="newsblock">
    <div>
        <div class="newsentry">
            <div class="newstitle">News 1</div>
            <div class="newstext"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsentry">
            <div class="newstitle">News 2</div>
            <div class="newstext"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="newsentry">
            <div class="newstitle">News 3</div>
            <div class="newstext"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Etc. -->
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Ignore the script below. It is just filling in the news' text. -->
<script>
  $(".newstext").each(function(i, newstext){
    $.get("http://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler&format=html&paras=5&num=" + i)
      .then(function(ipsumHtml){
        $(newstext).html(ipsumHtml);
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: http://loripsum.net is pickier about cross-domain. Apparently in SO snippets, origin becomes `null` which it doesn't allow. I could not fix that so I used the other one.

Comment: Works perfect. I can't say it often enough: Thanks! You reeeeeaaallly helped me a lot with this. I like that the only really change in your Solution is to think out of the box by literally setting the 'close' event to the outer box :D

Comment: I'm glad it helped! You may need to deal with the scroll though. When you are going from the first news to the second for example, you ends up at the middle of the news. I guess you may want to scroll back to its top.

Comment: I have to figure out how to handle the scroll bar at all, but i guess :) thats only a topic for a new thread if i really can't find the answer myself.

Comment: jquery's `scrollTop` is probably a  start. The hardest part is to figure out where to scroll to. Maybe you can just add a `step` function on `slidedown` and make sure the title of news being opened is always visible.

Comment: I could not help myself from giving it a shot. Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".newsentry, .newsblock").hover( // <-- changed
        function() {
            $(this).children(".newstext").stop(true,true).slideDown();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children(".newstext").stop(true,true).slideUp();
        }
    );
```

This makes sure the block stays open when you hover either over the header or the block itself.

Is that what you mean?

Comment: In this case when mouse will enter the scroll bar, all the children will slideDown and all of them will slideUp once mouse leaves .newsblock

Comment: I've made the changes but the behavior is still the same. As soon as i leave the newsentry block, the news collapse and the scrollbar disappear. Btw i've editied the HTML Block above, the newsentrys are not direct children of the news block. They are deeper within it.

Answer (score 0):

It will be a lot better if you use click operation instead of hover to slide down news text block because the user can accidentally hover over any of the news entry in order to reach for the scroll bar. I think you need a accordion like functionality. You can use the below code if you are fine with click instead of hover.

```
$(".newsentry").click(
        function() {
            $(".newstext").stop(true,true).slideUp();
            $(this).children(".newstext").stop(true,true).slideDown();
        }
    );
```

Or use the below one to go with hover.

```
$(".newsentry").hover(
    function() {
        $(".newstext").stop(true,true).slideUp();
        $(this).children(".newstext").stop(true,true).slideDown();
    },
    function(){}
);
```

This will not close the news text block until you accidentally hover over another news entry.

Comment: Great Idea, i already see that this problem will raise. If for example have two news, one very long and one short one. As soon as i hover the first one, and try to get to the next one. I will leave the first news, which collapse it and "move" the 2nd one way up before i even can catch it with the mouse. Not very user friendly i guess :)

Comment: Bad news, i am not allowed to change it to click or better said, i am not allowed to change the requirements :/

Comment: In that case you may go with the hover solution listed in my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There would be a joke , if i am wrong .. what i thing just change your css as

```
/* not .newsblock **/
      #newsblock {
                height: 200px;
                overflow-y: scroll;/* not auto*/
            }
```

Comment: If i do this a.) the scrollbar is always visible (which clearly should not be the case b.) the JS would still collapse the newstext as soon as i leave it and therefore the scrollbar in the newsblock will disappear. Except you tell me there is a difference between class and id which have an effect here.